# Selenium IDE javascript regex replacement of newline with <br>

Tags: javascript, regex, selenium-ide

I have a variable (${Short}) which is a body of plain text, with new lines. I have this stored in Selenium IDE and would like to replace the newlines. This is what I am using, any suggestions why it is not working?

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars.Short.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');}</td>
    <td>Short</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks for any insights. This regexp works fine in a js file..

Answer (score 0):

Use storeEval instead of store. If you echo ${Short} in your example above you're likely to see

> javascript{storedVars.Short.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');}

instead of the former contents of Short executed post regex.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I did notice that the regexp changes to .replace(/(?:\\r\n|\\r|\n)/g, '<br />') - notice the extra \ before \r

Comment: BTW the error message says "[error] Unexpected Exception: SyntaxError: unterminated regular expression literal. " Thanks @DMart

Comment: That's weird, it worked for me. I think the problem is now in your regex. Try it with a test regex like .replace('/ab/', '123') to prove it's working. Otherwise try escaping all \

Comment: Oh wait, I get what you were saying. Ya, looks like this issue:  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1816

Comment: Hi @DMart, that is just the issue I am having - spot on. My best workaround so far has been to use a regex: `/\s?$/` which can identify to the end of one line, which can then be appended to another line etc. a poor mans' work around I guess, in case anyone else is having trouble.